# Javascript - Como fazer o atributo data de um li pertencer à outro li

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<p class="question"><span class="mark-question">1.</span> Relacione as fabricantes aos seus veículos</p>
<ul class="first-column">
    <li class="ford" data-answer="0,5">Ford</li>
    <li class="fiat" data-answer="2">Fiat</li>
    <li class="renault" data-answer="3">Renault</li>
    <li class="ferrari" data-answer="">Ferrari</li>
    <li class="honda" data-answer="4">Honda</li>
    <li class="chevrolet" data-answer="1">Chevrolet</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-column">
    <li class="edge">Edge</li>
    <li class="onix">Ônix</li>
    <li class="palio">Palio</li>
    <li class="sandero">Sandero</li>
    <li class="civic">Civic</li>
    <li class="fusion">Fusion</li>
    <li class="fusquinha">Fusquinha</li>
</ul>
```

Queria relacionar estes lis através do javascript. (Exemplo: Fazer com que honda pertença à civic)
Desculpa se a dúvida for besta, porém, não consegui achar uma resposta ainda

Comment: qual sua intenção com isso?

Comment: Definir as respostas do exercício para depois, poder realizar uma função para quando clicar nos itens errados e outra para quando clicar nos certos. Mas para isso, os lis tem que estar relacionados

Comment: não deu pra entender ainda, tenta esclarecer mais a sua dúvida.

Comment: Quero definir as respostas para esse pequeno exercício que estou montando, e, para isso, utilizei o parâmetro data para poder relacioná-los com a outra tabela. Queria poder indicar para o javascript que a li "honda" pertence a li "civic". No caso do data-answer do honda é 4. Queria mostrar para o programa que aquele data-answer pertence à li civic. Esclareci um pouco?

Comment: Não está claro o suficiente, mas pelo que entendi, você precisa ter uma forma de agrupar os `<li>`s. Se for o caso, o próprio `<ul>` faz isso. Coloque um atributo `id` em cada `<ul>` (ex: `<ul id="marcas-de-carro">`) que você será capaz de pegar todas as `<li>`s pela `<ul>` pai.

Comment: Então quer dizer que não preciso do parâmetro data?

Comment: Ao clicar em um item da primeira <ul> o que deveria acontecer ?

Comment: Nada, só deve acontecer alguma coisa depois que ele clicar na primeira <ul> e depois na segunda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de checagem da resposta através da procura do valor com comparação via expressão regular devido ao fato de poder conter várias respostas:

```js
// Monta o Select para checar a relação
var $select = document.createElement('select');
var $firstLis = document.querySelectorAll('.first-column li');

for(var i=0; i<$firstLis.length; i++) {
  var $option = document.createElement('option');
  $option.innerHTML = $firstLis[i].innerHTML;
  $option.setAttribute('value', $firstLis[i].getAttribute('data-answer'));
  $select.appendChild($option);
};

var $secondLis = document.querySelectorAll('.second-column li');
for(var i=0; i<$secondLis.length; i++) {
  $secondLis[i].appendChild($select.cloneNode(true));
  $secondLis[i].appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
}

// Verifica as respostas
addListener(document.getElementById('check-answer'), 'click', function() {
  var $lis = document.querySelectorAll('.second-column li');
  
  for(var i=0; i<$lis.length; i++) {
    var validator = 'Incorreto';
    if(new RegExp("," + i + ",").test(',' + $lis[i].querySelector('select').value + ',')) {
      validator = 'Correto';
    }
    $lis[i].querySelector('span').innerHTML = validator;
  };
});

// Helper function addListener
function addListener(element, eventName, handler) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
  else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
  }
  else {
    element['on' + eventName] = handler;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="question"><span class="mark-question">1.</span> Relacione as fabricantes aos seus veículos</p>
<ul class="first-column">
    <li class="ford" data-answer="0,5">Ford</li>
    <li class="fiat" data-answer="2">Fiat</li>
    <li class="renault" data-answer="3">Renault</li>
    <li class="ferrari" data-answer="">Ferrari</li>
    <li class="honda" data-answer="4">Honda</li>
    <li class="chevrolet" data-answer="1">Chevrolet</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-column">
    <li class="edge">Edge: </li>
    <li class="onix">Ônix: </li>
    <li class="palio">Palio: </li>
    <li class="sandero">Sandero: </li>
    <li class="civic">Civic: </li>
    <li class="fusion">Fusion: </li>
    <li class="fusquinha">Fusquinha: </li>
</ul>

<button id="check-answer">Verificar Resposta</button>
```

Comment: Essa resposta seria perfeita se estivesse em javascript puro :(. Tenho certeza que o programa ficaria bem maior, porém estou começando e ainda não tenho muito conhecimento em jquery. Mas o que estou querendo fazer é algo bem parecido com o que você fez

Comment: @PedroLucasFlor Alterei para JavaScript puro ;)

Comment: Melhorou demais, tirou minha dúvida incial, porém só não entendi a função dessas linhas "(var i=0; i<$lis.length; i++)"; O que isso faz na função?

Comment: @PedroLucasFlor Essas linhas fazem um loop para executar as ações para cada elemento, no caso, para cada tag LI.

Comment: Aaah sim, muito obrigado mano!

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar saber previamente quem pertence a quem para poder relacionar. 
Exemplo:

```js
let marcas = [{
    marca: ' ford',
    modelo: 'Edge'
  }, {
    marca: ' ford',
    modelo: 'Fusion'
  }, {
    marca: ' fiat',
    modelo: 'Palio'
  }, {
    marca: ' renault',
    modelo: 'Sandero'
  }, {
    marca: ' ferrari',
    modelo: 'ferrari'
  }, {
    marca: ' honda',
    modelo: 'Civic'
  },
  {
    marca: ' chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Ônix'
  }, {
    marca: ' vw',
    modelo: 'Fusquinha'
  }
];

let carros = document.querySelectorAll('.second-column li');

// percorrendo cada elemento li
carros.forEach((carro) => {
  
  // filtra qual marca possui o modelo da li que está em foco
  // quando encontrar adiciona uma nova classe na li
  // com o nome da marca
  marcas.filter(i => i.modelo == carro.innerHTML).forEach(selecionado => carro.className += selecionado.marca )
})
```

```html
<p class="question"><span class="mark-question">1.</span> Relacione as fabricantes aos seus veículos</p>
<ul class="first-column">
  <li class="ford" data-answer="0,5">Ford</li>
  <li class="fiat" data-answer="2">Fiat</li>
  <li class="renault" data-answer="3">Renault</li>
  <li class="ferrari" data-answer="">Ferrari</li>
  <li class="honda" data-answer="4">Honda</li>
  <li class="chevrolet" data-answer="1">Chevrolet</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-column">
  <li class="edge">Edge</li>
  <li class="onix">Ônix</li>
  <li class="palio">Palio</li>
  <li class="sandero">Sandero</li>
  <li class="civic">Civic</li>
  <li class="fusion">Fusion</li>
  <li class="fusquinha">Fusquinha</li>
</ul>
```

Adicionei a mesma classe da marca no modelo.

Comment: Entendi o programa até a linha de "let carros = document....". Poderia me explicar melhor o que as últimas linhas do programa fazem exatamente??

Comment: Editado @PedroLucasFlor, veja se ficou mais claro pf.

Comment: Brigadão mano, ficou bem mais claro sim!!

Comment: Seu código ficou interessante, só não gostei da repetição das marcas. Deveria fazer algo do tipo `ford:fusion,edge; volks:fusca,gol...` daí com a marca selecionada o script verificaria os modelos atribuídos à marca.

Comment: Na verdade pensei em fazer dessa forma @DavidSamm, mas para filter deixei separado.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer colocar uma lista dentro de outra, como o exemplo:

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Lista</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Honda</li>
  <li>Fiat
    <ul>
    <li>Palio</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
    <li>Uno</li>
    <ul>
        <li> Novo </li>
         <ul>
         <li> 2017 </li>
                <li> 2018 </li>
                <ul>
                 <li> Versão SP </li>
                </ul>
         </ul>
        <li> Way </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Nissan</li>
   <ul>
     <li> Cerato </li>
        <li> Soul </li>
    </ul>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```